# Is this a valid mathematical proof of a linear indepedence?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

$\mathbb R^n$ is a Euclidean space. $b_1, b_2, b_3 \in \mathbb R^n$ are vectors such that $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ is linearly independent. I need to prove that the set  $\{b_1, b_2, b_1 + b_3\}$ is linearly independent.

Proof by contradiction, assume that $\{b_1, b_2, b_1 + b_3\}$ is linearly dependent. 
If $\{b_1, b_2, b_1 + b_3\}$ is linearly dependent, there exists some scalars $x_1, x_2, x_3$ not all equal to zero such that $x_1b_1 + x_2b_2 + x_3(b_1 + b_3) = 0$. 
Let $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 1$.

---

We get $x_3(b_1 + b_3) = 0 \implies $ 
$x_3b_1 = -x_3b_3 \implies$ 
$b_1 = -b_3$

Because $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ are given to be linearly independent, $b_1, b_2$, and $b_3$ cannot be linear combinations of each other. But here we get $b_1 = -1 \times b_3$. So $\{b_1, b_2, b_1 + b_3\}$ cannot be linearly dependent, meaning it is linearly independent.

Comment: Your proof isn't valid because you chose $x_{1} = x_{2} = 0$ and $x_{3} = 1$.  You can't do that here.  Why? Because when you assume they are linearly dependent, **all that tells us is that there exist some scalars (not all zero) such that the sum is $0$**.  We can't choose any scalars we want and have the sum still be $0$.  That's what you did -- you went from saying "we know there exist some scalars" to saying "Ok, I'm going to pick three scalars and assume these are the right ones."

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to do this which is still similar to yours.

To prove that $\{ b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{1} + b_{3} \}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors of $\{ b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3} \}$ is, we need to show that the only way $c_{1}b_{1} + c_{2}b_{2} + c_{3}(b_{1} + b_{3}) = 0$ is when $c_{1} = c_{2} = c_{3} = 0$.

But, notice that $c_{1}b_{1} + c_{2}b_{2} + c_{3}(b_{1} + b_{3}) = (c_{1} + c_{3})b_{1} + c_{2}b_{2} + c_{3}b_{3}$.

Also, we know $\{ b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3} \} $ is a linearly independent set by assumption, which means the only way for $(c_{1} + c_{3})b_{1} + c_{2}b_{2} + c_{3}b_{3} = 0$ to be true is if we have:

$c_{1} + c_{3} = 0$

$c_{2} = 0$

$c_{3} = 0$

But if $c_{3} = 0$ and $c_{1} + c_{3} = 0$, then that must mean $c_{1} = 0$, which means the only way for $c_{1}b_{1} + c_{2}b_{2} + c_{3}(b_{1} + b_{3}) = 0$ is if $c_{1} = c_{2} = c_{3} = 0$, and that proves that $\{ b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{1} + b_{3} \}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors.